# Terminal in Intellij IDEA does not have JAVA_HOME and java command

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, cmd, terminal

I have my command prompt (cmd) and it does show everything even if I go to the same path i'm in Intellij, but in Intellij `java` command and `JAVA_HOME` environment variable isn't set.

I have set environment variables in system as well as in user settings (Win 10)

Here is output of terminal from intellij:

```
D:\IdeaProjects\(Project)>java -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


D:\IdeaProjects\AirbentPluginIF>gradlew dokka

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

While output of cmd:

```
D:\IdeaProjects\AirbentPluginIF>java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)


D:\IdeaProjects\AirbentPluginIF>gradlew dokka
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :dokka
... (more stuffs)
```

**What could be the reason for this?**

Comment: Did you change the env variables `PATH` and/or `JAVA_HOME` while your IDE was still running? If so, this could be the reason why the internal terminal did not yet know the variables... Environment variables seem to be loaded while the IDE starts and not when they are requested... (similar to cmd itself... if you set env variables while you have a terminal open, the new or adapted env variables will still contain no or the old value)

Comment: Its been fixed, it was maybe because Intellij overwrites the env variables from terminal. I've accepted the answer that did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **Environment Variables** under **Preferences/Tools/Terminal**, try setting the value as:

**JAVA_HOME=path to your java home**

[image]